# Why is this cast ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that I have written which does type erasure.  The public interface is:

```
template <typename T>
value(const T &t);

value(value &&v);

template <typename T>
operator T() const;
```

When I create a value instance from a std::string I have no problems, everything works as expected.  When I try to get the std::string back out, using `static_cast<std::string>(val)`, where `val` is an instance of value that is holding a std::string, I get the following error from VS2012:

> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'value' to std::string'
>
> No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

If I comment out the templated cast operator and add `operator std::string() const` then it compiles.  I figure that something between the std::string constructors and the templated cast operator have the same goodness of match.  Could anyone suggest what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Does the error message show the candidates?

Comment: Please provide a compiling example (as much as possible up to the error in question).

Comment: here's a minimal example which I wrote: http://codepad.org/XJ2Jv5fT

Comment: Here's the same example with a better error message: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cda4dd42fa

Comment: VS2012 gives no more explanation of the error than I included in the question.

Comment: You really want it to work? `std::string( myValue, 0, std::string::npos )`. It's super-fragile if the constructors of `std::string` change though, and inefficient too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Igor explained the problem. Here's my suggested solution:

Your class is obviously only intended to store one type of object at a time, so make that explicit. Replace the conversion functions with a real function:

```
template <typename T>
T get() const;
```

Now call it like this:

```
std::string myString = myValue.get<std::string>( );
```

No ambiguity. No chance of the wrong function being called and messing everything up. And I'd argue that it is now more readable.

Answer (score 7):

`std::string` has several constructors capable of being called with one parameter - e.g. one taking `const string&`, and another taking `const char*`. What should `T` resolve to, then?

From the C++ standard:

> 5.2.9p4 Otherwise, an expression e can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`.

In your case, the declaration `std::string t(val);` is ill-formed.

Comment: `std::string`, as provided by the cast. What it is constructed from depends on the code in the function.

Comment: I can see what you mean by this answer, but it would seem logical to me that it chooses to follow a direct (single-stage) conversion to `std::string` in preference to any indirect (two-stage) conversion to a parameter which can be passed to a constructor for `std::string`

Comment: @Neil Kirk: "5.2.9p4 Otherwise, an expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`". In this case, the declaration `string t(val);` is not well formed.

Answer (score 5):

Following works with std::string (if you can return a reference).

```
static_cast<const std::string&>(val);
```

Comment: confirmed http://codepad.org/w7VKXUcs. This is interesting. I wouldn't have thought to cast to a reference. Not very readable though, so I'd avoid it in real code unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Very interesting and novel solution!